# Woocommerce get selected variation in quote form using gravity forms

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, gravityforms

I've been struggling with this thing for quite some time now, and really hope someone out there has a solution for this..

I'm trying to build this custom "ask for a quote" function in woocommerce using gravity forms and want to fetch the selected product variations and pass it through a simple text field in gravity forms. I've been able to get the product sku or title and stuff like that with this filter:

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_value_selected_variation', 'get_selected_product' );
function get_selected_product( $value ) {

  global $product;
  return $product->get_name();

}
```

Let's say I would fetch the sku and wanted it to be updated on selecting a variation where the product gets a new variation sku. Obviously, this code won't update. I guess I need some ajax or js to make this happen. **But how?**

Basically. I want to get all selected options of a product and pass them on in an email via gravity forms. Is it possible?

Comment: You could save the selected options to the product item and print it out later in the mail. Since I can only help with basic WC because I don't customize plugins, I can't help you but maybe my idea helps you.

Comment: I've thought about that but I guess I'm thinking it also would be nice for the buyer to see the spec in the form before sending it away.